# Definition of first fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding the first fundamental form of a manifold. Here are the definitions I'm working with (from Milnor's *Morse Theory*):

> Let $M$ be a $k$-manifold differentiably embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ for some $k<n$. Suppose a region of $M$ has coordinates $(u^1,\dots,u^k)$. The inclusion map $M\hookrightarrow\mathbb R^n$ defines functions $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Let $\vec x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.
>
> Then define the **first fundamental form** to be $$(g_{ij})=\left(\frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial u_i}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial u_j}\right).$$

(I assume Milnor's $u_i$ and $u_j$ are supposed to be $u^i$ and $u^j$ here?)

From what I could tell from Wikipedia, this form is supposed to act as the inner product, namely by taking $(v,w)$ to $v^T(g_{ij})w$. But this doesn't make a lot of sense, because Milnor says later that it will help to assume that the coordinates have been chosen so that $g_{ij}$, evaluated at $\vec q$, is the identity matrix, which means that $(g_{ij})$ really does just act on a single vector. Could someone explain this? I feel like I'm missing something obvious in the definitions here.

Comment: No, the inner product is a symmetric bilinear form; it is not a linear map.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh okay, so basically the two definitions actually are a bit different? Thanks!

Comment: What two definitions are you talking about? You might want to learn some basic differential geometry of surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ before reading this material. And if you don't know the difference between bilinear forms and linear maps, you should learn some linear algebra.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oops I figured out what I was confused about. Basically, I misread the Wikipedia article, so I thought that a Milnor’s linear map was supposed to be the same as the inner product, which made me kind of confused. But either way, I think you’re right, I think I learned only a bit of differential geometry and got kind of over-excited :)

Comment: When Milnor says that $g$ is the identity matrix $I$, he means $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ and the inner product of two vectors $v$ and $w$ is $v^Tgw = v^TIw = v^Tw$, i.e., the standard inner product.

Comment: @Deane Okay, that makes sense to me! Thanks :)